# NET Core 3.1 Microsoft.Identity.Web Role Based Authorization Issue

Tags: azure-active-directory, claims-based-identity, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm using an MS Code example from GitHub "Azure-Samples
/
active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2" to connect a .net Core 3.1 webapp to a single tenant in Azure AD.

The Micorsoft employee who's maintained this code sample did a recent webinar on 25th June 2020 where he did a high level overview in utilizing AppRoles for Roles based authorization in net core. The image below shows the code sample shown from his presentation which is using an older NuGet library 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI' for managing the login.

[image]

HOWEVER in the sample project code he used on GitHub, he's used the newer 'Microsoft.Identity.Web' library which does not appear to have any code section where I extract the roles claims from the token received back from Azure following a successful login authentication.

For Ref: the presentation from UTUBE - Title = Implement Authorization in your Applications with Microsoft identity platform-June 2020

For Ref: The MS code sample project  = https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/1-WebApp-OIDC

Code sample below:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Unspecified;
            // Handling SameSite cookie according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/samesite?view=aspnetcore-3.1
            options.HandleSameSiteCookieCompatibility();
        });

        // **THIS ONE LINER HAS REPLACED THE FORMER CODE SECTION FROM THE OLDER LIBRARY**
        // Sign-in users with the Microsoft identity platform
        services.AddSignIn(Configuration);

        services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
            options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        }).AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

        services.AddRazorPages();
    }
```

**I want to user Role Based access control on my MVC Controllers and Razor pages by decorating the methods with [Authorize(Roles = "ViewLogs")] but when I've logged in test the page, I get ACCESS DENIED so the there is some required code missing somewhere and i dont know what or where to add the required code to get this working.**

I have verified that I am receiving the Role "ViewLogs" successfully within the token received back from Azure after logging in, its just there is something vital missing here that .NET Core needs to in order to define the Roles policy check from the claims in the token.

Image below shows the Debug of the token contents:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the official ms sample for using roles with msal in .net core
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/5-WebApp-AuthZ/5-1-Roles#support-in-aspnet-core-middleware-libraries

It maps the roles claim to policies and groups, then it authorizes using the policy, however, I believe you can still authorize using roles or groups.
it also uses microsoft.identity.web (msal)

Answer (score 1):

Check the **HttpContext.User.Claims** collection to ensure that the `roles` claim are present,

[Edit]it seems they are.

Make sure the line **[app.UseAuthorization();](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/)** is present in Startup.cs in the *Configure()* in the right order.

Remove the [Authorize] attribute from the controller actions and execute the **HttpContext.User.IsInRole()** method in those actions to check the roles being acted upon as expected.

As advised by the asp.net core team, the sample advises using the new [Policy-based authorization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies)

if all the above do not work then create the project again using the steps provided [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/5-WebApp-AuthZ/5-1-Roles#create-the-sample-from-the-command-line). Note that .

Comment: Thank you Kalyan & alphaz, also good to see your example now uses the policy based authorization as this is what i had used in my previous standalone project using net core with the baked in identity. Do you have any idea how many Roles can be included in the ID Token returned back from Azure before it stops working? I know you mentioned this issue is usually associated with including too many groups in the token, but I assume there must be some limit with Roles as well given the limitations is liekly going to be the volume of info that the JWT can store? many thanks

Comment: The max number of roles cannot be calculated deterministically as its driven by the [limit of objects allowed in the app manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-app-manifest#manifest-limits). AAD approles works best with a few to upto a few hundres app roles.